# CouchDB Document Map Modification

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I am new to CouchDd so I may have missed something in documentation.

I want to create a map function that will drop on of the members of doc.  Note: I do not want to actually change the stored document only the result returned.

I have created this map.

```
function(doc) {
    for(i = 0; i < doc.Videos.length; i++)
    {
        delete doc.Videos[i].VideoFrames;
    }
    emit(doc.DeviceId, doc);
}
```

- doc.Videos is an array
- Each element of Videos has a memember VideoFrames.

I want to delete VideoFrames from the document returned by CouchDb.

When I run this map however VideoFrames are still in the returned document.  I ran this map with sample data in JSFiddle and it works as I would expect, however, when in couchDB it is not.

A sample doc

```
{
   "_id": "2e06de647c59fc94524c2f90b7001157",
   "_rev": "1-cb05705a122918c2c53dfb1e01ebed02",
   "TimeStamp": 1397343510,
   "DeviceId": "74a5f7aa9d4dfd0d",
   "Videos": [
       {
           "TimeStamp": 1397343518798,
           "VideoFrames": [
               {
                   "TimeStamp": 1397343519515,
                   "JPEG_Base64Frame": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh...==\n"
               }
           ]
       }
   ],
   "GeoLocations": [
       {
           "TimeStamp": 1397343512,
           "Latitude": 41.5654724,
           "Longitude": -87.5268132
       }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CouchDB seals `doc` object preventing it from any modifications since it been passed thought all map functions from the same design document on view index update. If you want to modify it and emit result, you should make his copy first and modify that copy instead of original `doc` object.

Answer (score 2):

#### Edit

I misunderstood the question. It seems that op just wants to remove video frames from the final result. Here is how you can do that

```
  function(doc) {
    var newDoc = doc;
    for(i = 0; i < newDoc.Videos.length; i++)
    {
        delete newDoc.Videos[i].VideoFrames;
    }
    emit(doc.DeviceId, newDoc);
}
```

Comment: I do not want want to update the actual document I just do not want the Video Frames returned with the result of the map.